# Open, resize and position Terminal App

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, window, terminal.app

Dow anyone have a script that opens a new terminal window, resizes it and then positions the window somewhere specific on the desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a look at [this bookmark](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100130231939451) which might be useful.

Also, if you're new to Applescript-ing, you might give [this quick introduction](http://www.macinstruct.com/node/68) a shot.

Hoping this helps.